# Не могу понять пример с итератором

Tags: stl, итераторы, c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::generate_n(std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(v), // can be simplified
                    10, [](){ return std::rand() % 10; });        // with std::back_inserter
    for (int n : v)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

А точнее эту строчку :

```
std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(v), // can be simplified
                        10, [](){ return std::rand() % 10; }
```

и эту  :
    int n : v

Так вот в первом вообще какой-то бред в виде реализации функции в вызове другой функции. А во втором явно не деление и на тернарный оператор не похоже.
Так что это?
Взял отсюда [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

То, что вам непонятно, появилось отностельно недавно в стандарте [C++11](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)

"реализация функции в вызове другой функции" есть не что иное как лямбда-функция - особая форма записи анонимной функции. И нет, это не бред, это действительно удобная штука, без которой ежегодно умирало по сотне маленьких невинных котят.

А что касается

```
for (int n : v)
```

то да, это не деление и не тернарный оператор, это так называемый [range-based for](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html), аналог foreach из других языков программирования, или более удобоваримая с точки зрения синтаксиса форма работы с итераторами.

И то. и другое позволяет писать значительно более краткий и удобочитаемый код - в первом случае программист избавляется от необходимости перегружать код лишними функциями, единственное предназначение которых - быть единожды вызванными в какие-то вспомогательных целях (кстати немаловажный побочный плюс еще и в том, что нет необходимости искать, где эти вспомогательные функции реализованы, так как их реализация находится там, где они используются), во втором - писать громоздкие конструкции с итераторами и begin() end() для элементарной операции итерации по контейнеру.
Также с этими двумя близко связано другое нововведение - ключевое слово auto (точнее, его новый смысл)

об этих нововведениях можете почитать [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/182920/)

Comment: Спасибо! Кстати ссылка на хабр была в закладках на будущее, потому что не хотелось бы устраивать кашу в голове и раз уж начинал со старого стандарта, то хочу пока закрепить его лучше, а потом уже лучше понимать зачем нужны нововведения в новом стандарте и как их оптимально использовать. Но раз уж столкнулся, то прошелся только по этим понятиям). Может это и неправильный путь, но от обилия в C++ и так иногда разрывает.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуем разобрать частями, написав код в cтаром стиле.

```
std::generate_n(std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(v), // can be simplified
                10, [](){ return std::rand() % 10; });
```

Можно заменить на 
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        v.push_back(std::rand() % 10);
    }

Здесь std::generate_n - функция, применяемая для заполнения контейнера. Она принимает указательна начальный итератор, количество элементо и метод реализации. Соответственно std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(v) - итератор, указывающий на место для первого вставляемого элемента, 10 - количество элементов и { return std::rand() % 10; } - метод генерации этих элементов.

Перейдем к следующему кусочку.
    for (int n : v)
        std::cout << n << ' ';

Заменим на:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << *it << ' ';
}
```

Этот цикл служит для обхода контейнера, так называемый foreach. здесь n - конкретный для итерации элемент контейнера v.

Answer (score 3):

`std::generate_n` это [такая функция](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate_n/) из стандартной библиотеки с тремя параметрами. Ничего необычного.

Ей, согласно документации, нужно три параметра - итератор для вставки, кол-во этих вставок и функция-генератор значений для вставки. С вторым параметром проблем не должно быть. 
Первый параметр - [итератор для вставки](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_insert_iterator/). По простому говоря, это такая обертка для контейнера, которая может добавлять элементы в конец (для вектора она просто дергает `push_back`).

Третий параметр - сложнее. Это обычная лябда-функция. Но их просто нужно изучить.

Переводя на привычный язык, этот участок кода запишется так

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  v.push_back(std::rand() % 10);
```

Что короче, а что красивее - это дело вкуса и требований.

`for (int n : v)` - а это новомодный foreach. Появился в новом стандарте. Он просто последовательно присваивает `n` значения вектора и обрабатывает в цикле. То есть, просто

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
  int n = v[i];
  //
}
```